# Is this true that ${({f^{ - 1}}[0,\infty ))^o} = {f^{ - 1}}(0,\infty )$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Continuous function.

Is this true that ${({f^{ - 1}}[0,\infty ))^o} = {f^{ - 1}}(0,\infty )$?

Comment: The requirement that it's not identically zero doesn't really invalidate my point, you just need a slightly more clever example.

Comment: right-hand side is always contained in the left-hand side, but the converse (as Ian pointed out) is not true in general; counter-question, find a sufficient condition (an extra requirement on $f$) to make equality true.

Answer (score 2):

No, because it could be that $f$ attains the value zero at an interior point of $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$. For instance $f$ could be identically zero, in which case the left side is $\mathbb{C}$ and the right side is $\emptyset$.

Comment: Is this tru that ${({f^{ - 1}}(0,\infty ))^o} = {f^{ - 1}}(0,\infty )$?

Comment: @Abc Yes: the set whose interior you are taking is open by continuity, so it is equal to its own interior.

Comment: @ Ian - Thanks.